# Underscore/jQuery template comments issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, underscore.js

I have this strange issue with _.template (or jQuery (or my knowlege of both)). I use Underscore to render templates and jQuery to append elements to DOM (and lots of other things). 
Like this:

```
var $section = $(this.tmpl.section(data));
```

Everything works great, however when I add a html comment inside template html, like

```
<script id="section-template" type="text/template">
    <!-- Section panel -->
    <div class="panel section-panel panel-info section-<%= type %>" data-type="<%= type %>" data-layout="<%= layout %>">
        <div class="panel-heading section-handle">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><%= title %></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I receive an array of objects. I am probably missing some basic stuff here, but is this the way jQuery supposed to work given this html on input? I thought it's supposed to ignore comments.

Comment: try using <%-- Section panel --%>

Comment: in scripts `//` triggers comments

Comment: @ejay_francisco Do you have a reference regarding non JavaScript scripts ?

Comment: `<%-- Section panel --%>` doesn't work, and `//` comments work, but that's Underscore comments, they're not shown in the html code, I wanted to have some tiny nice bits of comments on front-end) But thanks for advice, anyway. Probably the only way without adding any extra-logic is to include comments inside the div, but that's not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @dystroy you mean the MIME types? try [This](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/)

Comment: @ejay_francisco I mean : do you have a reference comments should be // in a "text/template" script ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Underscore, this is just jQuery getting confused about how many tags are in that string: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/E8Caq/ Why are you trying to put a comment in your template anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already understood, that it's not related to Underscore. The reason I try to add comments is because I think it'll make my html code more readable in inspecor, so to say. Actually, it's not like I'm trying to add them now, it's more like they've been there and it worked fine, until I tried to store a variable via .data on one of objects and that failed. I just thought jQuery treats comments as comments, not as normal tags. My bad)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this can work for you, but I use the same tools on this way:

- In my frontpage (a index.html page usually) I make a reference to my template

`<script type="text/html" id="desktop" src="partials/desktop.html"></script>`
    `<script src="js/app.min.js"></script>`

- Then in my main script (a app.min.js) I load the template this way:

  `$.get($("#desktop").attr("src"), function (res)
  {
    var template = res;
    $("body").html(_.template(template));
  }`